# Standalone Atmega328p AU PCB noise problem

Tags: atmega, pcb-design

I am using my standalone atmega 328p au custom PCB for switching 220v contactor via relay module. PCB contains 5v smps power supply, triac based SSR for indicators and output pins which connects with external relay module.

This all setup works but atmega freezes randomly at time of switching relay(which switches contactor). I am aware that back emf due to contactor creates this problem. So to suppress back emf I have taken following measures:-

1. Isolated relays optically i.e. separate power supply for relay module, no common GND
2. Isolated atmega power source i.e. powering through battery
3. Used MOV at contactor contacts
4. Used RC snubber at contactor contacts
5. Relays already have flyback diode

These measures hugely impacted the frequency of freezing but not eliminated it completely. Then I simply replaced my custom pcb with arduino pro mini and then the whole system is working perfectly. Even I removed all the safety measures that I mentioned above and still there are no freezing at all !

Then I came to a conclusion that problem is with my Atmega pcb, and most probably fault is in ground planing. I doubt that ground plane is acting as antenna and can catch even little noise due to emf.

Please help me finding flaws in my current PCB and also I designed new standalone atmega pcb please let me know if I am repeating same mistake again.

I am attaching pictures of my PCB, assuming that whole architecture is not needed here. Still if that is required, let me know.

**OLD PCB TOP**

[image: OLD PCB TOP]

**OLD PCB BOTTOM**

[image: OLD PCB BOTTOM]

**NEW PCB TOP**

[image]

**NEW PCB BOTTOM**

[image]

**NEW PCB SCHEMATIC**

[image: NEW PCB SCHEMATIC]

**NEW PCB TOP ACTUAL**

[image]

**NEW PCB BOTTOM ACTUAL**

[image]

Comment: It's very hard to see in the PCB drawings. Does the old PCB have a pull-up resistor on the reset pin?

Comment: How are those two PCBs related? They are vastly different! I can't understand from the question. PS On the new PCB the 5V for the ATMega is coming from three sides, creating three big loops. Do the same as you did on the first board, and connect the Vcc pins of the ATMega on the top layer. Though I'm not convinced that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: I agree with timemage but I also wonder what is MOV. Also I can suggest some additional debug steps:1-  did you try adding more pysical distance between MCU and relay. 2-  Can you connect MCU's power pins to oscilloscope to see what happens during the crash time? And finally some heavy power filtering on those pins is also considerable. And.. I remember a little, when I was switching selonoid valves with Mega, I had to use really big diodes.

Comment: @user30878, probably a [metal oxide varistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor);  High transient voltage filter basically.

Comment: @Gerben Sorry for the confusion. Actually the old pcb also have triac based ssr and power supply circuit along with atmega circuit. I could have been uploaded only the atmega part but I thought that whole thing might help a little bit more to debug. Regarding the vcc loop, I'll fix that and update.

Comment: @Gerben I've removed vcc loops and updated new pcb images in question.

Comment: Any views on the new pcb?